# Can openblas do matrix multiplication with multi-threads in fortran?

Tags: multithreading, matrix, fortran, openblas

In my fortran code, matrix multiplication is handled with 'dgemm' in openblas library.
The size of matrix is quite big, 7000 X 7000, so I want to reduce the computational cost in the matrix manipulation.

I tried to call 'dgemm' using multi-threads, but it seems not working (working as single thread only). The 'time' command is used to record the required time to calculate. Regardless I use -lpthreads flag or not, my calculation time is the same. It seems to me that the multi-threading is not working.

The below is my test.f and compile command. Can you recommend the way that I can use multi-threads in my matrix manipulation? Sorry about the duplication of questions and too simple and fundamental things, but the existing Q&As are not working for me. Thank you for any comments!

- In bashrc :

export OPENBLAS_LIB=/mypath/lib

export OPENBLAS_INC=/mypath/include

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

export GOTO_NUM_THREADS=4

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4

- command for source :

gfortran test.f -o test.x -lopenblas -lpthread

- sample source

  ```
    program test

    implicit none

    integer :: i, j, k
    integer :: m, n, num_threads
    double precision :: alpha, s
    double precision, allocatable :: aa(:,:), bb(:,:), cc(:,:)

    call openblas_set_num_threads(4)

    m=7000

    allocate(aa(m,m))
    allocate(bb(m,m))
    allocate(cc(m,m))
    aa=1.d0
    bb=2.d0
    cc=0.d0

    write(*,*) 'initialization over'

    ! calculate matrix multiplication using library
    alpha=1.d0
    call dgemm('N', 'N', m, m, m, alpha, aa, m, bb, m, alpha, cc, m)

    write(*,*) 'matrix multiplication over', cc(1,1), cc(m,m)

    endprogram test
  ```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You wrote: *"but it seems not working."*, what does that mean? How *exactly* does it seem?

Comment: Thank you. When I use -lpthreads flag or not, the calculation time is the same. So I think the multi-threading is not working. The calculation time was measured using time command as, 'time ./test.x'.

Comment: Hw do you measure the time? How do the measurement results look like? How is OpenBLAS configured and installed?

Comment: The time was measured by running the program as : time ./test.x    The result says to me that 'real 0m27.679s, user 0m26.692s, sys 0m0.893s', no matter the '-lpthread' is considered or not.   The openblas was configured and installed as default.

Comment: What you mean as default? Which default? From source or distribution binary? Which distribution? Which OS?

Comment: And why do you even link the `-lpthread`? Did you try enabling OpenMP? Did you verify it isn't using multiple threads all the time?

Comment: In my Linux I am getting 385% CPU all the time, I am actually struggling to persuade it to use just one thread.

Comment: accoding to this page, https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/faq#buildoptions is it possible to check how the library was built? (I tried " integer :: openblas_get_parallel ; print * , openblas_get_parallel() " on my mac, and it gave 2.)

Comment: Thank you roygvib and VladimirF. In my machine, OpenBLAS was re-installed to turn-on USE_OPENMP=1. Now the multithreading seems working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever number of threads you are trying to set in `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS`, `MKL_NUM_THREADS` or whatever other environment variable, it does not matter at all. In your code you have

```
call openblas_set_num_threads(4)
```

and that has the priority and you will always get those 4 threads if at all possible.

The `-lpthreads` is, as far as I understand it, useless. It is normally linked automatically and when you get no linker error it means it is not acually required to be linked explicitly.

In my tests with your code I always get around 17 seconds to run your code because of the `call openblas_set_num_threads(4)`. When I changed it to one, I got 25 seconds. It is a simple laptop and other stuff is running. The important thing is that it also changes from 385% CPU to 99% CPU.

I use the default binary OpenBLAS included in OpenSUSE.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. My system is in fedora OS. I installed the openblas using yum command. I got exactly the same running time around 27 seconds for both openblas_set_num_threads(1) and openblas_set_num_threads(4). Also, for both cases, 99% CPU is obtained. Does it mean that my system is working with a single thread?

Comment: @fortcome Yes, very likely a single thread. The Fedora OpenBLAS may be compiled differently from my OpenSUSE one. You can try to compile it yourself and configure it in a different way. You may try to compile your code with `-openmp` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: compile with 'gfortran test.f -o test.x -lopenblas -fopenmp -lpthread' and run with call oepnblas_set_num_threads(4) gives me the same result. Is there any other stuff needed to run with openmp?

Comment: @fortcome You likely have to compile OpenBLAS yourself. It is not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable optimization for parallelization to take effect, i.e. compile as such

```sh
gfortran -O test.f -o test.x -lopenblas -lpthread
```

Note the `-O` switch.

Comment: How does it affect the precompiled OpenBLAS in particular? It should have no effect whatsoever. Did you verify it does anything?

Comment: my setup uses blas suppied via intel's mkl but even so it only used 1 core w/o optimization and 4 using optimization.

Comment: Wait, OpenBLAS in MKL? MKL has its own implementation of BLAS. They are really different, this https://medium.com/@shaalltime/benchmark-numpy-with-openblas-and-mkl-library-on-amd-ryzen-3950x-cpu-96184f91057f compares the two.

Comment: I actually get zero difference for -O0 and -O3 on my system for this program. All the work is done is in OpenBLAS and that is precompiled.